# Importing module passed as parameter

Tags: python, python-import

My intention is to import a .py module that is passed as an argument:

```
module = str(sys.argv[3])
mymod = __import__(module)
```

However, I run into "ImportError: Import by filename is not supported.". Note that the passed module name is different on different invocation, and there is no common file path. What would be the workaround?

Comment: [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) detected. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: In any case, [works on my machine](http://i.stack.imgur.com/jHzbf.png). Maybe the problem is in the part of the code you haven't shown us.